# Next greatest number

Tags: java

I'm trying to find the next greatest number from the user input.If the user gives 23 it shows the output as 32.If there is number greater number then it has to print the same given number.But if the user gives 03 it shows 3 but it has to show 30.Because it takes 03 as octal number.How can i change the code to show the correct output as 30?

```
public class Main
{
 static void swap(char ar[], int i, int j) 
 {  
  char temp = ar[i];
  ar[i] = ar[j];
  ar[j] = temp;
 }
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   int num = in .nextInt();
   char[] chars = ("" + num).toCharArray();
   int i;
   int n = chars.length;
   for (i = n - 1; i > 0; i--)
   {
    if (chars[i] > chars[i - 1]) 
     break;
   }
   if (i == 0) 
    System.out.println(num);
   else {
    int x = chars[i - 1], min = i;
   for (int j = i + 1; j<n; j++)
   {
    if (chars[j] > x && chars[j]<chars[min])
     min = j;
   }
   swap(chars, i - 1, min);
   Arrays.sort(chars, i, n);
   for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
     System.out.print(chars[i]);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.demo;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Demo {

    static void swap(char ar[], int i, int j) 
    {  
     char temp = ar[i];
     ar[i] = ar[j];
     ar[j] = temp;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      //int num = in .nextInt();
      char[] chars=null;
      String numStr=in.next();
      int num= Integer.valueOf(numStr);
      if(numStr.startsWith("0")) {
          chars= ("0" + num).toCharArray();
      }else {
          chars= ("" + num).toCharArray();
      }

      int i;
      int n = chars.length;
      for (i = n - 1; i > 0; i--)
      {
       if (chars[i] > chars[i - 1]) 
        break;
      }
      if (i == 0) 
       System.out.println(num);
      else {
       int x = chars[i - 1], min = i;
      for (int j = i + 1; j<n; j++)
      {
       if (chars[j] > x && chars[j]<chars[min])
        min = j;
      }
      swap(chars, i - 1, min);
      Arrays.sort(chars, i, n);
      for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
        System.out.print(chars[i]);
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: Answer with no text, no comment, no explanation values nothing ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int findNextGreatestNumber(int[] arr, int k) {
    int delta = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int res = 0;

    for (int a : arr) {
        if (a - k > 0 && a - k < delta) {
            delta = a - k;
            res = a;
        }
    }

    return delta == Integer.MAX_VALUE ? k : res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the numbers from standard input as integers.  Try reading them as strings instead:

```java
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   String num = in.nextLine();
   char[] chars = num.toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `main()`,take the input as String only, instead of taking it as integer.
`String num=in.next();`